# Hotspot/Access Point not working, no connection whatsoever

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi, access-point

I followed a tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laeOmNDE-Ac) that would essentially turn your Raspberry Pi into a hotspot/access point. I did the exact same processes he did, even looking at the Pi Documentations to see if I had missed anything. I just intended on connecting my pi to any ethernet port and sharing that wifi with others.

Although the network would appear on my other devices, it did not have any proper internet connection. The Pi itself could not pick up anything from its ethernet connection or wirelessly from the main router.

I am using the latest version of Raspbian, Pi Model is 3B+.

Please help me, I am confused as to where in the procedure I messed up on.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I am confused as to where in the procedure I messed up" Rather than following some random video (Why would anyone make a video rather than instructions) try the Foundation tutorial [Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) or one of the alternate approaches on this site. We don't know **what YOU did**

Answer (score 0):

Because the information in the question is rather scarce, and "some random video" (as @milliways calls it) of more that 20 minutes doesn't help much, we will resort to basic fault searching. Use https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md as reference material.

You state that the network appears on other devices. That would mean that the SSID is broadcasted. Can those other devices connect to the Pi? Can they `ping` the Pi? If that is the case, the wireless part is OK.

See if the other devices get an IP address. If they don't get an IP address, verify your DHCP  configuration. Also verify that on those other devices the default gateway is the IP address of the Pi (that is: the address of the pi on the wlan).

Next, see if the Pi can access the Internet. From the Pi, `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`. Does that work? If not: check your Internet connection and make it work.

If this all works, then your routing on the Pi may be probably wrong. Check  if `/etc/sysctl.d/routed-ap.conf` has

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

in it.  Depending on your network, you may want the Pi to masquerade (otherwise your Internet router will need to have a static route to your new Wifi subnet via the Pi). Do

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If that solves the problem, make those rules permanent:

```
sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

If this doesn't help, check the logs in `/var/log`.